# TauDEM not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-000732, taudem

I am having issues using TauDEM. The official website (http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/) is offline. I managed to find an installer on another site, but I get an error when I try to launch any function in ArcGIS, and despite installing the various tools suggested in the forums I visited I could not solve the issue. I always get an Error 000732 related to the output file and to CalculateStatistics. See print screen:

[image: Print screen]

I feel that just being able to access the proper files could solve this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi, wellcome here! Did you try this function with another raster?

Comment: Have you checked version compatibility? The reported Execute Error "Parameters are not valid" hints at the frequent changes in syntax that ESRI introduces to arcpy at version changes.

Answer (score 1):

I finally contacted the producer and he sent me a link to the updated version and it works.

For anyone having similar issues, the official site should be back online shortly hopefully, and with the latest, official download there should be no problems.